# Choosing $n$ and $k$ in combinations

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

We have $5$ kinds of ice cream with each kind having $10$ pieces. For orders containing $10$ icecreams, how many different combinations are possible? The answer should be $1001$

= we are choosing from $5$ kinds of ice cream so $n = 5$ and $k = 10$

using formula

$\binom{n + k - 1}{ n } = \binom{ n + k - 1 }{ k - 1 }$ so
$\binom{ 5 + 10 - 1 }{ 5 }$ but this equals to $2002$.  But if I choose $k = 5$ and $n = 10$, it will results in $1001$, which is the correct answer$\ldots$ So why do we have to choose $n$ as $10$ and not $5$? We are choosing from $5$ different kinds so it should be $5$.  Or am i mistaken?

Comment: Make sure that you understand what the letters used in the formula are meant to represent.  $\binom{bins+balls-1}{bins-1}$.  Here, the flavors (five of them) act as the bins, and the number of scoops act as the balls.

Comment: I thought i do , using example when we have 6 red 6 blue and 6 green balls and we have to find the number of ways how we can take 6 balls we choose n=3

Answer (score 1):

Ordering 10 icecreams out of 5 kinds, is nothing else as putting 10 balls into 5 bins. So $k=5$ and $n=10$ in full agreement with the correct answer.

Possibly you misinterpret the meaning of $n $ and $k $ in the expression
$$\binom {n+k-1}n. $$

The correct meaning can be easily memorized using [stars and bars approach](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).